# Support for encoding /decoding json request/response in ElasticSearch

Tags: protocol-buffers, elasticsearch, messagepack

Can I have a custom Protobuf/MessagePack encoding/decoding module in Elasticsearch, so that request from my client and response from server can be encoded.

Comment: Hi @anaray , i am also trying something similar.  I am currently using Elastic search and kibana for application and access log analysis. Json logs are saved in elastic search. I am currently using JSON for the same but using Protobuf or Avro will have huge positive impact. Please share your thoughts and findings.